# Java application terminates at getOutputStream()

Tags: java, android, outputstream

I'm creating an application for our Android devices. The aim of this section is to post a username and password (currently just assigned as a string) to a web service and to receive a login token. When running the code, at the getOutputStream() line, my code terminates and will no progress any further.

I have assigned the android emulator GSM access and also set the proxy and DNS server within Eclipse. I'm not sure where to go with it now!

This is within my onHandleIntent():

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i) {
    try{

        HttpURLConnection http_conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.XXXXX.com").openConnection();

        http_conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http_conn.setDoInput(true); 
        http_conn.setDoOutput(true); 
        http_conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 

        String login = URLEncoder.encode("XXXXX", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("XX", "UTF-8");
        login += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("XXXXX", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("XX", "UTF-8");



        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(http_conn.getOutputStream());
        //TERMINATES HERE
        wr.write(login);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http_conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = rd.toString();

        wr.close();
        rd.close();

        http_conn.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
}
```

This is my first go at java and have only been writing it for a few days so bear with me if I've missed something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: this is a very important question, getOutputStream() method defautl implementation throws `UnknownServiceException("protocol doesn't support output")`

Comment: also it is never wrong to close your streams in finally block

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out that I'd forgotten to add the INTERNET permission within the manifest, bit a newbie mistake I guess. Only problem now is it is hanging on the BufferedReader line so will work through that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to POST something using HTTP, why not use HTTP POST? ;-)

Here is an example snippet:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: If you want to POST something using HTTP, why not use HTTP POST? One ans for the question may be android guys are asking developer to use HttpUrlConnection over HttpClient. However there are contradictory opinion abt the performance of either API.

Comment: Can you hint me to where "android guys" are asking developers to use HttpUrlConnection over HttpClient? I'm interested.

Comment: @chruli http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the appropriate answer, but will certainly be helpful to you. I have used this code for sending and receiving the request and reply resp, to a webservice.

This code is working, but will need some `Refactoring`, as i have used some extra variable, which are not needed.

I have used the `NameValuePair` here for Post

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {



        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();


        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);


                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;


                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }


                    Log.d("Check Now",sb+"");




                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } /*
                 * catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (SAXException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = rd.toString();
```

should be

```
String line = rd.readLine();
```

that might do the trick. `rd.toString()` gives you a String representation of your `BufferedReader`. It does not trigger the HTTP operation. I did not test your code, so there might be other errors as well, this was just the obvious one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will take a look at the readLine() and change it over!